# check if file is image

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to check if file is image. and then you will see a link where you can see the image. But the link only has to appear if file is link. I try it like this:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.FileName)) {
    var file = item.FileName;
    string[] formats = new string[] { ".jpg", ".png", ".gif", ".jpeg" };
    if (file == null || file.Contains(formats)) {
        viewLink = false;
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FileName)
        <em>(@Resources.Entity.Environment.Removed)</em>
    }
    else {
        @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Id )*@
        <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "FormLibrary", new { id = item.FileName})"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-external-link-square text-info"></i></a>
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
 if (file == null || file.Contains(formats)) {
```

Comment: What error/exception message do you get ?

Comment: That's not an error, it's a line of code that likely produces an error. Can you post the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
string.Contains(string array)
```

Instead you have to rewrite that line of code to this:

```
if (file == null || formats.Any(f => file.Contains(f)))
```

And this can be shortened down to:

```
if (file == null || formats.Any(file.Contains))
```

Comment: Note that a file named "test.gif.exe" will be identified as an image. Also, file names should be compared ignoring the case on windows machines.